# react native share in a single application

Tags: react-native

In my react-native app, I want to share a text message with a specific application, e.g whatsapp or texting application without having to first land on the dialog with all the social applications.

For instance if I press the share button and whatsapp is called directly.

I tried using [`react-native-share`](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) but it seems to not be working anymore.

Comment: single or multiple images sharing using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html), *which gives you a general interface to interact with both incoming and outgoing app links*.

For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Linking, Button } from 'react-native';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button
              onPress={() => {
                let url = 'whatsapp://send?text=Hola Mundo';
                Linking.openURL(url).then((data) => {
                  console.log('open whatsapp')
                }).catch(() => {
                  console.log('App not installed')
                });
              }}
              title="Whatsapp"
              color="#4FBE3C"/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: @sebastian I couldn't understand what should be the URL ? If I want to share pdf or jpeg files on whatsapp what will be the URL in that case ?

Comment: I couldn't understand what should be the URL ? If I want to share pdf or jpeg files on whatsapp what will be the URL in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, the React Native Share module uses the default ACTION_SEND android intent:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

In order to have a different behavior, you need either write our own RN plugin that would talk to the app you want it to (if such feature is available) or find a similar plugin on npm.

I assume your plugin should do something like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

Comment: Thanks @Yury .I searched for an npm plugin to no avail.Let me implement this and give feedback