# React Native - can we share an image and text into whatsapp?

Tags: image, react-native, whatsapp

I've spent an hours to find a way to send/share an image (and text if possible) into whatsapp app using react native,

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496422/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp) (in android) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179221/react-native-share-in-a-single-application) (using linking)

on android, it is possible to send image and text to whatsapp, but on react native i don't see any way to archieve it,

anyone have an idea?

Comment: You don't need the `linking library`, you need the new [`sharing library`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html) or you may use the following [package](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share)

Comment: @PritishVaidya do you have any reference code about how to integrating sharing lib with whatsapp?

Comment: I think you should check this [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) library

Comment: @flix were you able to achieve this? Do you have any code snippet for the same?

Comment: @cauchy nope, i just change my app flow

Comment: @flix asked a fresh question again.

Comment: @cauchy i wouldn't, it must be duplicated if am ask similar question about this, let it be like that and just wait for the right answer

Comment: Did you find a solution for iOS eventually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905965/5079876 -> Please check out this answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 19):

For react-native versions greater than 0.56.0 the social share functionality is already implemented in the library, so extra libraries like [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) are no longer needed and they could be unmantained. In fact, I was using [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) library some months ago for older versions of react-native and I migrated the corresponding code to the react-native implementation that exports a Share class that has a [share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share#share) method and it's very easy to use.

Then, you can use [share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share#share) method to share data and react-native will know what apps have the phone installed. In the following image you can see how the sharing screen looks like in an Android phone with WhatsApp application installed:
[image]

And this is how it would like in an iOS simulator with no app installed:
[image]

Here you can find an example of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Share,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

const shareOptions = {
  title: 'Title',
  message: 'Message to share', // Note that according to the documentation at least one of "message" or "url" fields is required
  url: 'www.example.com',
  subject: 'Subject'
};

export default class ShareExample extends React.Component {

  onSharePress = () => Share.share(shareOptions);

  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSharePress} >
        <Text>Share data</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally you have to options to send the **image + text** message:
- You can use the url field of the shareOptions adding the remote URI of the image so it can be previewed in the WhatsApp message, and the title or subject fields to add the text.
- You can share a base64 file url like this:
`url: 'data:image/png;base64,<base64_data>'`

Comment: Double checking: Does the image share functionality works on Android as well? Looks not to me, since the url attribute is only available for iOS (as the documentation says).

Comment: You are right, you I think you could just add the image URL in the field `message` so WhatsApp will try to put the corresponding image resource in the message.

Comment: Indeed, doable by using `Platform` to determine if Android or iOS (to use message or url).

Comment: @NachoJusticiaRamos I want to share pdf and jpeg files on whatsapp, gmail, etc. through react native app so in case of pdf and jpeg files what should be the changes required in `shareOptions` ? Will URL change if I am sending pdf or jpeg or png file ?

Comment: @funjoker URL changes when sending different types of files.
- For jpeg would be: 
url: "data:image/jpeg;base64,<base64_data>"

- For png:
url: "data:image/png;base64,<base64_data>"

- And for pdf or other files you can do:
url: "file://<file_path>"

Comment: @NachoJusticiaRamos Ok got it thanks your answer is very helpful. Upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks!! Indeed, you can take a look at docs of react-native-community/react-native-share: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share#url-format-when-sharing-a-file. Althought you should not use it because React-native already have this functionality, they explain pretty well in the Readme the **url** prop in the section "Url format when sharing a file".

Comment: The Share API that comes with React Native (not the react-native-share library)  is not able to show dataUrl as image.  On Android, If I put the `dataUrl` for a qr code in `message`, it is just plain text in whatapp, gmail. I'd like to know how to show the actual image of the qr code.

Comment: @RedGiant I have same requirement. Did you get any solution? I am using deep link  const whatsappDeepLink = 'https://wa.me/phoneNumber?text=Message';
Linking.canOpenURL(whatsappDeepLink)

Comment: @user1915370 , I ended up using `react-native-share`. I use it to share images in whatsapp, gmail, twitter etc. The one bundled with React Native cannot attach images on Android.

Comment: Same issue for me image + message not sending in ios only android working fine

Comment: Not working for me i tried both react-native-share and Share both but IOS whatsapp not working.

Comment: can we send url & message together in iOS?

Comment: how can we send it to a specific number

Comment: react-native-share is a terrible library. Poorly documented and not up to date.

Comment: How to open WhatsApp directly?

Comment: You can open a whatsapp conversation directly by doing `Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text=' + message + 'phone=' + phone);`

Answer (score 6):

I was using react native 0.59 version but still i was not able to share image and text(including a link) on whatsapp because the default react native share gets either `message` or `url` so it is necessary to use react-native-share library https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share . I also used `rn-fetch-blob` library to convert image url to base64 image data.

```
shareImage= () => {
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', `https://example.com/example.png`)
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('response : ', resp);
    console.log(resp.data);
    let base64image = resp.data;
    share('data:image/png;base64,' + base64image);
  })
  .catch(err => errorHandler(err));

share = base64image => {
  console.log('base64image : ', base64image);
  let shareOptions = {
    title: 'Title',
    url: base64image,
    message: 'https://somelink.com some message',
    subject: 'Subject'
  };

  Share.open(shareOptions)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      err && console.log(err);
    });
};
```

};

Comment: does this works for android app also, because as per document URL is only allowed in IOS only

Comment: Yes it works for android. The default react native share library only allows message or url but this library https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share allows both url and message(it is allowed for both ios and android in the docs), i have tested it on whatsapp on android and it worked.

Comment: Works on android, didnt work on iOS. On iOS either image or text is sent

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-multi-share if you want share multiple picture at the same time :)

https://github.com/chuangbo/react-native-multi-share